# Application.stop(...) in Elixir shell

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, cowboy

I am programming a simple application in Elixir using Plug and Cowboy and mix. After executing:

```
$ iex -S mix
```

the application starts. If I execute

```
iex(1)> Application.start(:web)
{:error, {:already_started, :web}}
```

I get the expected output. However, when I try to stop the application using the following command:

```
iex(2)> Application.stop(:web)
:ok
```

I get the `:ok` but then I get lots of messages including the following:

```
iex(3)>
09:36:43.689 [info]  Application web exited: :stopped

09:36:43.691 [error] GenServer #PID<0.189.0> terminating
** (stop) killed
Last message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.187.0>, :killed}
State: {:state, {#PID<0.189.0>, :ranch_acceptors_sup}


:undefined, 1, 5, [], 0, :ranch_acceptors_sup, [ServeRequests.HTTP, 100, 
:ranch_tcp, [port: 4000]]}
09:36:43.691 [error] Failed to start Ranch listener ServeRequests.HTTP in :ranch_tcp:listen([port: 4000]) for reason :eaddrinuse (address already in use)
09:36:43.691 [info]  Application ranch exited: shutdown
nil
```

Am I doing something wrong in the code? Is this the normal behaviour?

The contents of the `mix.exs` file are the following:

```
defmodule Web.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :web,
     version: "0.1.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.2",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     deps: deps]
  end

  def application do
    [applications:
        [:logger, :cowboy, :plug],
        mod: {Web, []}
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
  [{:cowboy, "~> 1.0.3"},
  {:plug, "~> 1.1.2"}]
  end
end
```

The contents of `lib/web.ex` are the following:

```
defmodule Web do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      worker(Web.Router, [])
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Web.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

thanks,
Mihalis.

Comment: Please share your `mix.exs` config file. It looks like your application is stopped properly without errors (first line), but your node tries to restart ranch instantly before your operating system released port 4000. If you can share your entire project on GitHub, it would allow people to dig in.

Comment: Included the contents of `mix.exs`. Is there a way to release port 4000 or make the Supervisor wait a little?

Comment: @MihalisTsoukalos can you also post the contents of `lib/web.ex`?

Comment: I've checked that even with `start_permanent` the application shouldn't be restarted automatically when stopped with `Application.stop/1` so I am not really sure if I can help.

Comment: Contents of `lib/web.ex` added.

Comment: @MihalisTsoukalos so `Web.Router` uses `Plug.Router`? would it be possible to upload the whole code or try to replicate the error in a brand new app and upload that?

Comment: You can find all Elixir files of the project at https://github.com/mactsouk/Elixir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit subdocumented in the docs, and I now also see that I should have explained this in EiA (my bad). The gist is that you should use [Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.child_spec](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.html#child_spec/4) to properly insert the server in the supervision tree. Then, the server will be correctly stopped with the application.

Here's how it would look in your example (in `web.ex`):

```
children = [
  Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.child_spec(:http, Web.Router, [])
]
```

With that, you can get rid of `my_web_start` and `Web.Router.start_server` functions completely.

Trying it in the shell gives me:

```
iex(1)> Application.stop(:web)
:ok
16:44:29.929 [info]  Application web exited: :stopped

iex(2)> Application.start(:web)
:ok
```

And after that I can again access the page.

Comment: I have EiA and I could not find the solution there. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

- It says your address already in use (eaddrinuse).
- Try restarting device you are running on or check you don't have the program   open twice.
- Restarting will stop and start the program probably fixing Address In
  Use.

Comment: Why does the application fail to stop properly?